# Using MathJax in ClojureScript

Tags: clojurescript, mathjax, clojurescript-javascript-interop

I want to use MathJax in a ClojureScript program to typeset some math in
a DOM element, not the whole page (which works), just this one particular DOM element. (It's the live preview pane of a Markdown editor that also formats math in the Latex format.)

According to [this documentation page](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/advanced/typeset.html) on the MathJax site, you can use something
like this in JavaScript.

```
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, latex-node]);
```

I've been using trial and error and have not gotten it right. Something like this:

```
(defn typeset-latex
  [latex-node]
  (.Queue js/MathJax.Hub ["TypeSet" (.-Hub js/MathJax) latex-node]))
```

compiles and does not produce any errors when run, but does not yield any output either.

Using the `js*` macro to try to reproduce the method on the documentation page:

```
(js* "MathJax.Hub.Queue([\"TypeSet\", MathJax.Hub, \"mde-preview-id\"]);")
```

produces an error message in the browser stating that "Error: Can't make callback from given data".

**ALSO**: Assuming I can get the syntax right to get typesetting working in `figwheel`, any guidance on how to setup the externs file for use with an optimized build would be appreciated.

Comment: One debugging technique is to inspect the generated JavaScript: Enable `:repl-verbose` (https://clojurescript.org/reference/repl-options#repl-verbose) to see JavaScript for forms entered at the REPL, or `set!` `*print-fn-bodies*` to `true` then evaluate `typeset-latex`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close. I think you just need to make the Clojure vector into a JavaScript list. You can use the `#js` reader macro:

```
(defn typeset-latex
  [latex-node]
  (.Queue js/MathJax.Hub #js ["Typeset" (.-Hub js/MathJax) latex-node]))
```

[Here](https://github.com/exupero/grapple/blob/806ffd217335b4e244365d7fe3fa212e95882207/src/cljs/grapple/views.cljs#L48) is a line of code in one of my own projects that's equivalent, though it uses slightly different syntax.

Update: change `TypeSet` to `Typeset`.

Comment: Believe it or not, at one point I had almost exactly the same line that you point to in your Github project (using `latex-node` instead of `node`), and the browser threw the same error about being unable to construct a callback. I copied/pasted your line, and it worked. It turns out it was a capitalization error. I used "Type_S_et" instead of "Type_s_et"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about MathJax, but this template CLJS project has examples of 3 different ways of performing native JS interop from ClojureScript:

- https://github.com/cloojure/cljs-template

---

Looking at [the MathJax example](http://jsbin.com/?html,output):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>MathJax example</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" async
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/latest.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML" async>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>
  When \(a \ne 0\), there are two solutions to \(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\) and they are
  $$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

it seems straightforward. Can you give an example of what you're trying to do?